# How to launch leanback launcher in Android TV?

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher

As part of a project, client wants to create a custom home screen application for there Android TV replacing the default launcher. We were able to do just that. Now our client want to launch leanback launcher from the app just like any other app. I tried the following,

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.leanbacklauncher");
                startActivity(launchIntent);
```

but got the following error:

```
09-09 23:08:29.785: E/InputEventSender(2474): Exception dispatching finished signal.
09-09 23:08:29.786: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData()' on a null object reference
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1494)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at me.xxxxx.xxxxx.homescreen.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:21)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:9023)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:5953)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2643)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:8411)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2361)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1709)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2702)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2276)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4020)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3982)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3713)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3874)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2208)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1840)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2185)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
09-09 23:08:29.787: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2474):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
09-09 23:08:29.787: D/AndroidRuntime(2474): Shutting down VM
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474): Process: me.xxxxx.xxxxx.homescreen, PID: 2474
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData()' on a null object reference
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1494)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at me.xxxxx.xxxxx.homescreen.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:21)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:9023)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:5953)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2643)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:8411)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1495)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2361)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1709)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2702)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2276)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4020)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3982)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3713)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3874)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2208)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1840)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2185)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
09-09 23:08:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2474):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.leanbacklauncher");

PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
Collections.sort(resolveInfos, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

if (resolveInfos.size() > 0) {
    ResolveInfo launchable = resolveInfos.get(0);
    ActivityInfo activity = launchable.activityInfo;
    ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
            activity.name);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    i.setComponent(name);

    mContext.startActivity(i);
```

This code work for me.
But not for this package : com.android.tv.settings